# Octave-gui had crashed in macOS, how to fix it?

Tags: octave

After I installed octave by homebrew command:

```
brew install octave
```

, I start octave with gui by command:

```
octave --force-gui
```

But it had no response after I entered command

```
help sign
```

So I kill the process and tried to restart it. But octave-gui crashed immediately.
the error is : octave exited with signal 6
and I have the crash report:

```
Process:               octave-gui [12398]
Path:                  /Applications/Octave-4.4.1.app/Contents/Resources/usr/Cellar/octave-octave-app_4.4.1_0/4.4.1/libexec/octave/4.4.1/exec/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/octave-gui
Identifier:            octave-gui
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [12396]
Responsible:           octave-gui [12398]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-07-07 12:01:12.543 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.5 (18F203)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.5 (16P5200)
Anonymous UUID:        BFDE7534-3B4F-4F39-0D15-117761865994
...
```

I have tried restart my computer and reinstall the octave but the octave-gui still crashed.
please give me some help.

Comment: crosspost (even without mentioning brew) on the help mailinglist: http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Octave-gui-crashed-in-macOS-td4693307.html

Comment: Come on over to https://github.com/octave-app/octave-app/issues and report this as a bug. This is probably a support problem or application bug that's unlikely to get fixed on StackOverflow. (Though if some SO user does have a fix, I'd love to hear it!)